# I can't run my Ruby program and I see errors in the terminal. I can't find the program

Tags: ruby

Good afternoon! I have a problem with Ruby. I downloaded this program from the official site https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ on Fedora without any problems (using the command via the terminal). However, I cannot use the 'irb' command in the terminal to run Ruby on Linux as described here https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/. Therefore, I cannot learn the Ruby programming language.[Command 'irb' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGaBh.png)

I tried my best to run Ruby in other ways. One of them, as is customary in Fedora, is to write the name of the program in the terminal. But it opens a folder in which, I assume, Ruby is located (I can't find the folder itself either in Files or via the 'cd' command in the terminal). I kind of can open this folder in the terminal, but I can't find it in Files.
Oh, by the way, the 'irb' command doesn't work there. Only some real command for a program like this one will work: irb(main):001:0> "Hello World" (from https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/). [The program is and is not at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q51jH.png)

Move on. I made a text document, wrote irb(main):001:0> "Hello World" in it (as written in "Ruby in Twenty Minutes"), and saved the file as hello.rb . Opened the hello.rb file path through the terminal and wrote 'ruby hello.rb' (without quotes, of course). Result: syntax error. [hello.rb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oth3L.png) [Tried to open hello.rb via ruby in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dGaW.png)

Oh yeah, I almost forgot: when I tried to open hello.rb in Files through another application, there was no Ruby script in the list (ruby or irb or at least something through which one could open a .rb file). [No program for .rb format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ5iP.png)

I hope I have explained the problem in sufficient detail and clearly. And I hope for your help and understanding! In any case, good mood to you!

Comment: What version of Ruby did you download? How did you install Ruby? Was the installation successful? What was the output of the installation process?

Comment: On the page https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#yum, I installed Ruby on Fedora via the terminal (only replaced yum with dnf since the 'yum' command is deprecated for Fedora). I have ruby version 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-linux]. The installation was successful, but I do not remember what was written specifically. If needed, I can uninstall ruby and reinstall via terminal to see what happens.
https://imgur.com/a/NUOy9Vr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Fedora & CentOS, the Ruby installation is split into many smaller packages. If you want to run `irb`, you'll also have to install the `ruby-irb` package using `dnf install ruby-irb`.

Comment: Wow! It worked! Marcus, I am infinitely grateful to you for your help! It was so easy... Really, I want to know how you know this? The official Ruby Lang website didn't say this.

Comment: In this case it was just by chance: at work, we use CentOS a lot and I had the same issue a couple of days ago. I wanted to debug a Rails app on one of the servers and realised that it was running the app just fine, but `irb` was not available. So I searched for "ruby irb centos" and found the `ruby-irb` package.